# limit ordinal as a countable sequence

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

If $a$ is a limit ordinal then is it true that there exist (can it be increasing ?) $a_n < a $ such that $a= \bigcup \{a_n : n \in \omega \}$ ?

Comment: What definition of limit ordinal are you taking? This is pretty much the definition.

Comment: The definition $a = \bigcup \{b : b<a\}$ , but here we have countable many $a_n$

Comment: @Couchy: That is "pretty much the definition" if and only if $a_n=n$ and $a=\omega$.

Comment: The cofinallity of an ordinal $a$, denoted $cf(a)$, is the least cardinal of any  $b\subset a$ such that $\cup b=\cup a$..... And $cf(a)$ can be any $regular$ cardinal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this only holds if the ordinal has countable cofinality. For example, $\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal, has uncountable cofinality (assuming choice). That is, given a sequence $(a_n)_{n < \omega}$ with $a_n < \omega_1$, we have that each $a_n$ is countable and so $\bigcup_{n < \omega} a_n$ is countable. Thus we cannot have $\omega_1 = \bigcup_{n < \omega} a_n$.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the axiom of choice is required to prove that there are any ordinals of uncountable cofinality (specifically, countable choice is what's needed).  It's consistent with ZF for every limit ordinal to be cofinal with  $\omega;$ this result is due to Gitik.